# Swapping with draggable and droppable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI to implement DIV Swapping.

Problem: The problem of swapping is resolved but the CSS has some issue during swap. A scroll bar is coming at the bottom, also the div is changing shape during the swap. The Swapping is also looking so unprofessional :(

Can anyone tell me how to make it a smooth Swap ?

Example is [**here**](http://codepen.io/b0y/pen/BzQwmZ)

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Drag The Colored DIVs</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="drophere">
        <div class="draghere" style="background-color:yellow;">
          1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="drophere">
        <div class="draghere" style="background-color:pink;">
          2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="drophere">
        <div class="draghere" style="background-color:yellow;">
          3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="drophere">
        <div class="draghere" style="background-color:yellow;">
          4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 44 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 44 4 44 44
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="drophere">
        <div class="draghere" style="background-color:pink;">
          5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="drophere">
        <div class="draghere" style="background-color:yellow;">
          6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 66 6
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.draghere {
  margin:5px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.startPos = window.endPos = {};

  makeDraggable();

  $('.drophere').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'hoverClass',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $from = $(ui.draggable),
        $fromParent = $from.parent(),
        $to = $(this).children(),
        $toParent = $(this);

      window.endPos = $to.offset();

      swap($from, $from.offset(), window.endPos, 20);
      swap($to, window.endPos, window.startPos, 500, function() {
        $toParent.html($from.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: '',
          top: '',
          'z-index': ''
        }));
        $fromParent.html($to.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: '',
          top: '',
          'z-index': ''
        }));
        makeDraggable();
      });
    }
  });

  function makeDraggable() {
    $('.draghere').draggable({
      zIndex: 99999,
      opacity: 0.35,
      revert: 'invalid',
      start: function(event, ui) {
        window.startPos = $(this).offset();
      }
    });
  }

  function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
    $el.css('position', 'absolute')
      .css(fromPos)
      .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
        if (callback) callback();
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems fine to me. the only minor problem you have is the duration you specified for swapping. If you remove the 20 and 500 (specified duration) it should swap smoother and the scrollbar will no longer appear.

I updated your code as following:

```
  swap($from, $from.offset(), window.endPos, 0);
      swap($to, window.endPos, window.startPos, 0, function() {
        $toParent.html($from.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: '',
          top: '',
          'z-index': ''
        }));
```

**[Update]** If you want to keep the animation:

I created a sample in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjk6rpw8/4/) based on your code.

To solve your issue, I had to take control of the css. The `.drophere` should have css rules that reset the shape after animation.

Comment: Lemme try this out :)

Comment: Hey GH KARIM, i already tried this way, this is simply removing the animation. I want the CSS to animate :(

Comment: @b0y okay. I didn't appreicate that :-) . Please see updated answer!

Comment: Hey GH Karim, I cannot remove bootstrap, The project is too big to risk of removing it. I also tried keeping FLOAT but didn't worked(UI Disturbed) :((

Comment: Hello @b0y. The problem was that columns were resizing while animating. However, I managed to control it better now. Keeping your bootstrap. Hope this works!!

Comment: Hey kasim, still you have fixed the width of divs which i cannot, i think there is no solution to this problem. :(

Comment: @b0y which width. I didn't get it!